# I'm looking forward to install the hunspell package using pip, but it throws the following error:

Tags: python, hunspell

### Collecting hunspell
Using cached hunspell-0.5.5.tar.gz (34 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: hunspell
Building wheel for hunspell (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\shikhar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\shikhar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gur9qi9n\hunspell_590196089ad44370bc048a58cf3d40dd\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\shikhar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gur9qi9n\hunspell_590196089ad44370bc048a58cf3d40dd\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\shikhar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-5grngp_q'
cwd: C:\Users\shikhar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gur9qi9n\hunspell_590196089ad44370bc048a58cf3d40dd
Complete output (12 lines):
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_ext
building 'hunspell' extension
creating build
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHUNSPELL_STATIC -IV:/hunspell-1.3.3/src/hunspell -IC:\Users\shikhar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\shikhar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt /EHsc /Tphunspell.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\hunspell.obj /MT
cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/MD' with '/MT'
hunspell.cpp
hunspell.cpp(20): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'hunspell.hxx': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

ERROR: Failed building wheel for hunspell
Running setup.py clean for hunspell
Failed to build hunspell
Installing collected packages: hunspell
Running setup.py install for hunspell ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\shikhar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\shikhar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gur9qi9n\hunspell_590196089ad44370bc048a58cf3d40dd\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\shikhar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gur9qi9n\hunspell_590196089ad44370bc048a58cf3d40dd\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\shikhar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-clyqesxf\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\shikhar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\hunspell'
cwd: C:\Users\shikhar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gur9qi9n\hunspell_590196089ad44370bc048a58cf3d40dd
Complete output (12 lines):
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'hunspell' extension
creating build
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHUNSPELL_STATIC
-IV:/hunspell-1.3.3/src/hunspell -IC:\Users\shikhar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\shikhar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt /EHsc /Tphunspell.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\hunspell.obj /MT
cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/MD' with '/MT'
hunspell.cpp
hunspell.cpp(20): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'hunspell.hxx': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\shikhar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\shikhar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gur9qi9n\hunspell_590196089ad44370bc048a58cf3d40dd\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\shikhar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gur9qi9n\hunspell_590196089ad44370bc048a58cf3d40dd\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\shikhar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-clyqesxf\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\shikhar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\hunspell' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I tried an older version and successfully installed.

```
pip install hunspell==0.3.4
```

Comment: I tried this but it shows the same error again.

Comment: If that doesnt work:- pip install CyHunspell

Answer (score 0):

```
Collecting cyhunspell
  Using cached CyHunspell-1.3.4.tar.gz (2.7 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: cacheman>=2.0.6 in c:\users\abdul rehman\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from cyhunspell) (2.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: future>=0.16.0 in c:\users\abdul rehman\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from cacheman>=2.0.6->cyhunspell) (0.18.2)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil>=2.1.0 in c:\users\abdul rehman\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from cacheman>=2.0.6->cyhunspell) (5.9.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in c:\users\abdul rehman\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from cacheman>=2.0.6->cyhunspell) (1.16.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: cyhunspell
  Building wheel for cyhunspell (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [40 lines of output]
      C:\Users\Abdul Rehman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:771: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
        warnings.warn(
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
      copying hunspell\platform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
      copying hunspell\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
      copying hunspell\hunspell.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
      copying hunspell\thread.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
      copying hunspell\hunspell.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
      copying hunspell\hunspell.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
      copying hunspell\thread.hpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
      copying hunspell\hunspell.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\en_AU.aff -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\en_CA.aff -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\en_GB.aff -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\en_NZ.aff -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\en_US.aff -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\en_ZA.aff -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\test.aff -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\en_AU.dic -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\en_CA.dic -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\en_GB.dic -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\en_NZ.dic -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\en_US.dic -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\en_ZA.dic -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\test.dic -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\libs
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\libs\msvc
      copying libs\msvc\libhunspell-msvc11-x64.lib -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\libs\msvc
      copying libs\msvc\libhunspell-msvc11-x86.lib -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\libs\msvc
      copying libs\msvc\libhunspell-msvc14-x64.lib -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\libs\msvc
      copying libs\msvc\libhunspell-msvc14-x86.lib -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\libs\msvc
      running build_ext
      building 'hunspell.hunspell' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cyhunspell
  Running setup.py clean for cyhunspell
Failed to build cyhunspell
Installing collected packages: cyhunspell
  Running setup.py install for cyhunspell ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for cyhunspell did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [42 lines of output]
      C:\Users\Abdul Rehman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:771: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
        warnings.warn(
      running install
      C:\Users\Abdul Rehman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
      copying hunspell\platform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
      copying hunspell\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
      copying hunspell\hunspell.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
      copying hunspell\thread.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
      copying hunspell\hunspell.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
      copying hunspell\hunspell.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
      copying hunspell\thread.hpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
      copying hunspell\hunspell.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\en_AU.aff -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\en_CA.aff -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\en_GB.aff -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\en_NZ.aff -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\en_US.aff -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\en_ZA.aff -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\test.aff -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\en_AU.dic -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\en_CA.dic -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\en_GB.dic -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\en_NZ.dic -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\en_US.dic -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\en_ZA.dic -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      copying dictionaries\test.dic -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\libs
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\libs\msvc
      copying libs\msvc\libhunspell-msvc11-x64.lib -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\libs\msvc
      copying libs\msvc\libhunspell-msvc11-x86.lib -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\libs\msvc
      copying libs\msvc\libhunspell-msvc14-x64.lib -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\libs\msvc
      copying libs\msvc\libhunspell-msvc14-x86.lib -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\libs\msvc
      running build_ext
      building 'hunspell.hunspell' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> cyhunspell

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).